# Is "homework" countable?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I was wondering if "homework" is countable? I remember it is an uncountable noun when I learned English in middle school.

Suppose now I would like to ask my teacher to hand back my graded "homeworks" of last three times. How shall I ask him?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Homework" is uncountable since it is treated as a general meaning not a particular item, like "work", "money" etc.

In your case, use "assignment" instead.

> May I have my last three graded assignments back please?

Comment: Both 'work' and 'money' are countified and have well-documented plural forms. 'Homeworks' has not got the same pedigree, though some dictionaries license it with caveats.

Answer (score 8):

While I've seen the word *homeworks* used, I've never seen anything legitimate to indicate that it's correct. In any case, you can use the term ***homework assignments*** to refer to multiple homework items. That's a fairly common term, at least in American English.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't ask my teacher for assignments, but my homework that I have worked out and handed to my teacher, and the homework is from last three times. How shall I ask him?

Comment: @Tim: In American English, *assignments* is used for what you describe.  In British English, *homeworks* is at least marginally acceptable — we used it at at least one school I went to, although I do remember it feeling awkward/slangy to me at first.

Comment: What I’ve seen to indicate it is correct is its frequent use by native speakers

Answer (score 3):

**Traditionally,** it is not countable, and most dictionaries list it as such.

**However,** the *Merriam-Webster* **thesaurus** (although not the *Merriam-Webster* dictionary) does have an entry for *homeworks*. Moreover, the plural form is used by at least some groups of ***educated native speakers.***

One's best bet is to try to find out if one's audience belongs to a group that tends to use *homeworks*. If yes, then go ahead and use that word yourself. If not, rephrase as *homework assignments* or something similar.

## Discussion

### *Merriam-Webster* Thesaurus

Notice that the *Merriam-Webster* thesaurus has the [following entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/homeworks):

> ***homeworks*** noun
>
> plural of *homework*
>  Synonyms of *homeworks*
>
> as in schoolwork
>
> Synonyms & Near Synonyms for *homeworks*
>
> *schoolwork
>  assignments, lessons, reading
>  lectures
>  drills, exercises, practices* (also *practises*)
> *études, studies*

(Interestingly, the *Merriam-Webster* [dictionary entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homework) does not give a plural form for *homework*.)

### Examples of usage by educated native speakers

Such examples are not hard to find at all. For instance, American professors of ***linguistics,*** physics, and mathematics, at least, use the word *homeworks* quite frequently.

All of the examples below are from native speakers, as best as I can tell.

Here are **five** examples from **linguistics** professors:

*Final grades will be calculated as follows: 30% for **homeworks,** 20% for the midterm, …*
<sup>Penny Eckert and [Ivan A. Sag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Sag), *Linguistics 1: Introduction to Linguistics* (Syllabus), 2011, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210415122503/https://web.stanford.edu/class/linguist1/).</sup>
*Late assignments are not accepted, but your two lowest-scoring **homeworks** will be dropped.*
<sup>[Adam Jardine](https://web.archive.org/web/20211121193043/https://adamjardine.net/files/cv.pdf), *Introduction to Linguistic Theory (Honors)* (Syllabus), 2018, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211121192645/https://ling.rutgers.edu/images/Syllabi/615_201-H_Jardine_Spring-2018.pdf).</sup>
***Homeworks** are due at the beginning of class on the days indicated.*
<sup>Emily M. Bender, *Linguistics 461: Introduction to Syntax* (Syllabus),[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190121175829/http://courses.washington.edu/ling461/).</sup>
*If turned in ​complete​, the **homeworks** will be graded 8 (well below average), 9 (average), or 10 (well above average​); but 0 if not done.*
<sup>Anthony C. Woodbury, *Linguistics 306: Introduction to the study of language* (Syllabus),[here](https://utdirect.utexas.edu/apps/student/coursedocs/nlogon/download/10519591).</sup>
***Homeworks:** 25% (lowest score dropped)*
<sup>Dani Byrd and [Toby Mintz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZAuZ--Yeqo#t=2m54s), *Ling 275: Language & Mind* (Syllabus), 2006, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170627121633/https://sail.usc.edu/%7Edbyrd/syllabus_275.html).</sup>

Here are **five** examples from physics professors:

*Some **homeworks** are 'secret' assessment exercises: General GRE, Praxis and Major Field Tests* 
<sup>Richard Robinett, *Penn State Physics Undergraduate Program Better Practices,* 2010, p. 12 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150913003306/https://www.aapt.org/Programs/projects/spinup/upload/Penn-State.pdf).</sup> 
***Homeworks** are like sports practice*
 <sup>Tom Moore , *Teaching General Relativity with Tensors,* 2006, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150914122238/https://www.aapt.org/doorway/TGRUTalks/Moore/MooreTalk5of6.htm).</sup>
*These concepts can be introduced to students through labs, **homeworks,** and discussion questions.*
<sup>Brianna Billingsley and Cory Christenson, *Incorporating Non-Western Contributions Into the Intro Physics Curriculum,* 2019, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211120153636/https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019APS..MARG70107B/abstract).</sup>
*With their flexible design, PhET sims are used in many ways—as demos, **homeworks,** or inexpensive, accessible lab alternatives—and getting started is easy with our database of over 500 activities.*
<sup>Katherine K. Perkins, *Teaching Physics with PhET Simulations:
Engaging Students and Increasing Learning* (Abstract) 2012, p. 58 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210814173344/https://www.aapt.org/Conferences/wm2012/upload/aapt-program-final2a.pdf).</sup>
*In this talk, we will outline the reforms—including consensus learning goals, “clicker” questions, tutorials, modified **homeworks,** and more—and present evidence of the effectiveness of these reforms relative to traditional courses.*
<sup>Katherine K. Perkins, Steven Pollock, Stephanie Chasteen, Steve Goldhaber, Rachel Pepper, Michael Dubson, and Paul Beale, *Colorado's Transformed Upper-Division E&M and QM courses: Description and Results* (Abstract) 2010, p. 119 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210814025411/https://www.aapt.org/Conferences/sm2010/loader.cfm?csModule=security/getfile&pageid=25474).</sup>

And here are **five** examples from mathematics professors:

***Homeworks** 1-3*
<sup>David Blecher, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211120160223/https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Edblecher/3334H.pdf).</sup>
*There will be two midterm exams, weekly **homeworks,** and a final exam.*
<sup>Scott Sutherland, *MAT 141: Honors Calculus 1* (syllabus), 2012, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210424193810/http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Escott/mat141.fall12/syllabus/).</sup>
*MIT 3.016 **Homeworks***
<sup>W. Craig Carter, *Mathematics for Materials Science and Engineers, MIT 3.016* (syllabus), 2011, [(here)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200202095724/http://pruffle.mit.edu/3.016-2011/). Click on the link 'Problem Sets and Solutions'; you will reach [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20181209140757/http://pruffle.mit.edu/3.016-2011/Homeworks/), which is where the word *homeworks* appears (in the page heading).</sup>
***Homeworks** (41/42 Track); **Homeworks** (51 Track)*
<sup>Andrew Schultz, *SSEA 2006: Mathematics Track,* 2006, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211120162022/http://palmer.wellesley.edu/%7Easchultz/summer06/SSEA/homeworks_and_tests.html).</sup>
*All **homeworks,** except the first one, are due on Thursday at 3:30pm*
<sup>Mike Clancy and David Wagner, *CS 70, Spring 2005: Discrete Mathematics for Computer Science,* 2005, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210901041549/http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Edaw/teaching/cs70-s05/).</sup>

In searching for examples, I also saw examples of similar usage by professors of [comparative literature](https://web.archive.org/web/20211121203244/https://studylib.net/doc/9113494/world-literature-from-the-beginnings--cmpl-english-266-), philosophy, computer science, chemistry, and sociology.

Comment: Even Wiktionary fails to concede the plural form as a possibility, but this is doubtless an ongoing countification (and 10 years is a substantial time for the evolution to progress).

Comment: *American professors of physics and mathematics, at least, use the word homeworks...* I wonder if I should take seriously pronouncements on quantum physics by English professors...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I just looked at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homework), and it says 'usually uncountable, plural *homeworks* '. The edit that added that note was on 5 October 2015‎. So indeed, things change in ten years!

Comment: Whoops, I had [SimpleWiktionary](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/homework), which I didn't know existed. Obviously _homeworks_ is harder.

Comment: @Greybeard Apologies if your comment was meant as a joke, but if it wasn't (and for the benefit of those who don't take it as a joke), the answer is, no you shouldn't. And indeed, conversely, if physics or math professors were to start making 'pronouncements' about whether a particular word is acceptable English, you shouldn't take that seriously, either. But that's not what's going on in my answer. My answer simply points out that there is a U.S.-wide, loosely connected group of educated native speakers who rather frequently and unselfconsciously use *homeworks* in day-to-day life.

Comment: @Greybeard For good measure, I also added five examples by ***linguistics*** professors.

Comment: The reason for it is that those illustrious professors don't understand uncountable nouns. I wonder if there are English professors who use the plural form. What do linguistics and physics have in common? They are both professions where counting is a big deal.

Comment: @Lambie There is at [least one](https://web.archive.org/web/20211121203244/https://studylib.net/doc/9113494/world-literature-from-the-beginnings--cmpl-english-266-): *Regular homeworks to be handed in every day.*

Comment: @linguisticturn I was only half-joking. I can only see the plural as "outliers" (as they say in maths) or "sporadics" (as they say in geology) or "random particles" as they say in physics. :) It is possible to find anything on the internet, and I think you have done it. Stick to the uncountable homework - you'll not be wrong.

Comment: In your very first example, if you click on the link, the justification is apparent: Homework 1, Homework 2, Homework 3. Those are the numbered assignments given by the professor to the students. Ergo, calling them homeworks in this case is justified!

Comment: @Graybeard What about the entry in the [*Merriam-Webster* thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/homeworks)?

Comment: Third set of examples, I meant to say.

Comment: @linguisticturn Merriam-Webster -> MW -> Mostly Wrong. Seriously, I discount it. If you recall the history of MW, Webster attempted to introduce many weird spellings and words to American English the vast majority of which failed to attract buyers - I suspect that "homeworks" is "following tradition". I note the AE speakers here do not like "homeworks" either. Time to give up on this one... :)

Answer (score 0):

Ask for "items" or "pieces" of homework.